# Android horizontal date picker - Scrolling Tabs or specific ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, tabs, datepicker

### Background

I would like to create an application screen with layout shown on the image.

[image]

Layout has

- date picker, which should scroll horizontally (similar to Play Market tabs "Categories", "Main", "Top free", ..etc)
- ListView which shows all the events starting from picked date.

These two elements should be dependent on each other:

- if I scroll date picker and choose the date, ListView is updated and scrolled to show events starting from the picked date
- if I scroll ListView (e.g., to the 17th September), date picker element is updated appropriately (e.g., the 17th September is chosen)

### Question

1. Is there any available guideline for designing such a layout?
2. If not, what is an appropriate solution for "date picker" element? Tabs, or some ListView implementation?
3. If I use Tabs, will the be any performance problems (e.g., I have 2 months period to render, that being around 60 tabs)?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider

Have you checked this library
it is there what you need it baby

ListView and action much easy to create ..Date slider is pretty complicatied

Comment: Well, not exactly what I wanted, but thanks anyway. Now struggling to use the code somewhere outside of the Dialog